# Bad Printer Drivers -- How to completely remove?

Tags: windows, printer

I moved my printer (HP Officejet Pro K550) to another computer (running XP Pro) and something went wrong. Every time it printed it would stop mid-job, delete the job from the queue and the printer would indicate that it was jammed.

I think I've narrowed it down to bad drivers on that computer. The problem occurs when printing from any application and it works fine on a different computer. If I put the printer on another machine and add it as a network printer, it works fine.

I've deleted the printer, uninstalled the software, used a scrubber app from HP, updated the firmware. Went into `\windows\system32\spool` and deleted 2 folders relating to the printer. Searched for all the files that were in the driver download pack and deleted those. After all that, I try installing the printer again and it has the same problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue of the print driver conflicting with another process or program.  Have you tried booting into safemode and manually starting the print spooler service to see if it works?